# Are primary lysosomes same as vesicles budded off from golgi bodies containing hydrolyzing enzymes tagged with mannose-6-phosphate?

Tags: cell-biology

SO, as far as I understand, lysosomal hydrolyzing enzymes are first synthesized as proteins in rough ER and then they are budded off from the ER. The vesicles containing those proteins reach cis golgi and then they are properly folded to proper hydrolyzing enzyme but they are tagged with mannose-6-phosphate at this point, so they font have the ability to hydrolyze molecules just yet. In the mean time, some molecules can be engulfed by the cell and and these enter the cell as a membrane bound vesicle (endosome) containing proton pumps in its membrane which maintains an acidic environment inside the vesicle (which matures to late endosome). Vesicles containing hydrolyzing enzymes now move to those late endosomes and fuse with them. The low pH cleaves the mannose-6-phosphate tag from the enzymes and they become functional thus late endozome matures to lysosome.

The definition of primary lysosome says it is that lysosome that directly buds off from the golgi bodies and secondary lysosome is that lysosome which gets formed when primary lysosome binds with a vesicle and hydrolyse its content.

So are primary lysosme and those vesicles same?

Comment: What is the question here? If you want a fact check,  try wikipedia or if you are more academically inclined try searching on pubmed.gov for articles about lysosomes.

Comment: Flagged question, as this is more of a fact check, which the asker should perform personally.

Comment: The question is clearly visible at the top of the page. Then I mentioned what I know about them so far. Had wikipedia been an authentic source of information, I wouldn't have asked here. And I could not manage to find anything that answers my query in pubmed as well. Stop flagging my question for no reason, questions get flagged if there is no attempt of research has been shown. When it is shown, it becomes fact check. What do you want me to do?

Comment: Sorry for my french, but essentially you are asking a yes/no question, which you should be able to check yourself. I see that you have edited your question slightly, but the remain the same.